# Show page title just from the first child-page in template

Tags: templates, title, code

how can I do this:

Pages:

Home
- sub-1
-- sub-sub-1
--- sub-sub-sub-1

On home-page should only show the page-title of the **first child-page** like:
sub-1

I found this:

```
<?php $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."   AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
<h2 class="subpagetitle"><a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></a></h2>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

But it doesn´t work for me at all. The title will be show two times and show all child-page titles (sub-1, sub-sub-1, sub-sub-sub-1)

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class to do it:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
) );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2 class="subpagetitle">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </h2>
<?php endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I add this   `<?php
 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
) );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    <h2 class="subpagetitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();
?>`  // Browser show `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`

Comment: @ogni ah... sorry... forget about it. i have updated my answer, check it again.

Comment: Thanks works, but i would like to show on the home-page a lot of different sub-page titles (overview-page), at the moment every item has the same title-name?

Comment: it's hard to tell you what's wrong, without seeing your page. [sarcasm]my rating doesn't allow me to read your mind remotely[/sarcasm]

Comment: I make a screenshot with comments and load it up -j ust a moment, please

Comment: Just a simple painting: http://tiny.cc/1kkufw